# How to click a word on screen with pyutogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

The error I am getting is:

OSError: Failed to read Ok because file is missing, has improper permissions or is an unsupported or invalid format.

Can someone help me?

I’m using the command:

pyautogui.click(‘Ok’)

I was expecting this to click Ok on the screen when it pops up.

My code is:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MController
import pyautogui
import time

def Mid():

    keyboard = Controller

    mouse = MController()

    pyautogui.press('win')

    pyautogui.write('Change user account control settings')

    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.leftClick('OK')
```

Comment: No.  The `click` method merely takes an X/Y coordinate.  You have to watch for the thing you want to click and find its location.  If it's a button, `pyautogui` can help you find buttons.

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks

Comment: Can you give me the exact command @TimRoberts

Comment: If you want to find the x,y of a image on screen there is pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image.png)

Comment: @Gianpi I want to click the Ok button after typing in Change system control settings

Comment: You can locate it and click it after typing change system control settings, anyways posting your code would be more useful

Comment: @Gianpi I pasted my code can you check it and tell me what to do for the click?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  You should not be releasing software that changes the UAC settings.

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui.leftClick('OK')` will do nothing since pyautogui.click() will take x and y coordinates for example:

```
pyautogui.click(100,100) #will click at the coordinates x 100 and y 100
```

We can use locateOnScreen to get x,y coordinates of a image and then click it with pyautogui.click

In your case:

```
time.sleep(2)
#  Find yourimage.png in your screen
button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("yourimage.png")
#  Click at x,y of where the button is found on the screen
pyautogui.click(button)
```

Comment: It didn’t work it didn’t click the ok button. How do I identify the ok button with pyautogui? @Gianpi

Comment: `pyautogui` searches the screen looking for a rectangle that matches your image.  So, you need to grab a screenshot image of the `OK` button you want, and save it in a png file.  Once you have that, `pyautogui` can scan the screen looking for that button.